# Angular Testing Modules and override

Tags: angular, testing, module, karma-jasmine

I'm a beginer in angular testing and my question may be part of 'best practice in angular testing'.

I'm looking for a method to include smallest module in testing and overide some part that need to me mocked.

Let say I've got a button component that need the Router to work. Its module is like so :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyButtonComponent } from './mybutton.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyButtonComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    MyButtonComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    Router,
  ]
})
export class MyButtonModule { }
```

Now I want to test it like so :

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyButtonModule } from './viewer-button.module';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

// Tests Begining
describe('ViewerButtonComponent', () => {
  let component: MyButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyButtonComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ViewerButtonModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('#should create the component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy(' fail at creation');
  });
});
```

But the `Router` does no overide with `RouterTestingModule` imports. (got the `Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).` error)

I know a better way for this example is only to declare MyButtonComponent, then imports RouterTestingModule but I'm asking if there is a way to do this with larger component without the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`shallow thing.

For example:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // my childs component module
        MyChildComponentModule1,
        MyChildComponentModule2,
        ...
        MyChildComponentModuleX,

        //the modules that mock what needed (or use custom mock in the providers part)
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ....
        SomethingTestingModule
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RouterTestingModule` is for stubbing routing and navigation.

A few points here:

1) You shouldn't provide `Router` yourself in your widget module. Instead, you should add `RouterModule.forRoot()` to `AppModule` which will provide the `Router` service and its dependencies.

2) You shouldn't create mixed Angular modules, meaning **don't** provide **and** declare in a single Angular moudule.

3) Angular module import order matters. With this import order, `RouterTestingModule`'s provider will override the `Router` provider from `ViewButtonModule`.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    ViewerButtonModule,
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
  ],
});
```

4) You can always override a provider using the Angular testing module. For example

```
TestBed.overrideProvider(Router, { useValue: routerStub });
```

or

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub },
  ],
});
```

If you're interesting in learning more, you can keep my article [*Testing and Faking Angular Dependencies*](https://blog.angularindepth.com/testing-and-faking-angular-dependencies-886495057121) as a reference on those hard-to-remember details.

In 2020 I wrote these articles:

- [Testing Angular routing components with the RouterTestingModule](https://indepth.dev/testing-angular-routing-components-with-the-routertestingmodule/)
- [Testing routed Angular components with the RouterTestingModule](https://indepth.dev/testing-routed-angular-components-with-the-routertestingmodule/)